# Connecting from Spring boot to EJBs in Jboss project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss, ejb

Okay so I have a Spring Boot project that is supposed to run tasks in a different project, on a periodic basis.  It uses the various annotations in Spring Boot. The timed aspect is working fine.  So we'll call this **the Scheduler Project**

But the project is only supposed to run the timers.  All the heavy lifting of doing actual business processes is handled by a separate project.  Call it **the Do Stuff Project**

I'm having trouble crossing the gap between the Scheduler project and the Do Stuff project.  It seems like it's getting some of the way there.  The Do Stuff project has a fairly standard set of classes used to support the connection between itself and Spring Boot classes.

- SpringSchedulerService.java
- SpringSchedulerServiceImpl.java
- SpringSchedulerServiceEJB.java
- SpringSchedulerServiceHome.java
- SpringSchedulerServiceHomePooler.java
- SpringSchedulerServiceRemote.java

Besides this, there are several XML files with configuration stuff in them.

I refer to this as a standard set of classes because what I'm doing is not new to our organization.  We already have a different project, also based on Spring Boot, that connects into our Do Stuff project.  Call it the **Old Spring Project**.

So, okay.  Earlier I took code from code from my Scheduler project and set it up in the Old Spring project.  The processes ran and they successfully made the jump to the Do Stuff project.  This leads me to conclude that everything is set up perfectly in the Do Stuff project.

So the latest I have is that the Scheduler project will make it over to the Do Stuff project but sort of get stopped at the gate.  Scheduler manages to run **SpringSchedulerServiceHomePooler** where it tries to run this.

```
public class SpringSchedulerServiceHomePooler extends EJBObjectPooler {
    public SpringSchedulerServiceHomePooler() {
    }

   public void createHomeObject(Context ctx, String jndiName) throws NamingException{    
         SpringSchedulerServiceHome home = SpringSchedulerServiceHome) 
PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup(jndiName), SpringSchedulerServiceHome.class);
}
```

It can't execute this method successfully.  Once it gets to **ctx.lookup(jndiName)** it all blows chunks and throws a CommunicationException:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor; unable to create instance]

"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:611)"
"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:471)"
"javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)"
"com.ourcompany.gibson.services.user.ejb.SpringSchedulerServiceHomePooler.createHomeObject(SpringSchedulerServiceHomePooler.java:37)"
"com.ourcompany.util.pool.RemoteConnectionPool.registerPooler(RemoteConnectionPool.java:245)"
"com.ourcompany.util.pool.RemoteConnectionPool.registerPooler(RemoteConnectionPool.java:204)"
"com.ourcompany.util.pool.RemoteConnectionPool.acquire(RemoteConnectionPool.java:156)"
"com.ourcompany.gibson.client.remote.EJBServiceProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBServiceProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)"
"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.getUser(Unknown Source)"
"com.ourcompany.scheduler.services.TimerServiceImpl.runGenericProcess(TimerServiceImpl.java:28)"
"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
"org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)"
"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)"
"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)"
"org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)"
"java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)"
"java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)"
"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)"
"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)"
"java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
```

I threw in some println() calls to get some of these values that the method is using.

```
jndiName: gibson/SpringSchedulerService
java.naming.provider.url: localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.initial: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs: org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.  Those values from the println are the same for the Old Spring project, except that java.naming.provider.url is parameterized in that project.  Shows as @jndi.gibson.host@:@jndi.gibson.port@  instead, although the actual values underlying those are exactly the same.

I hope that all makes sense.

UPDATE (January 14) -- My latest hypothesis is that it's related to JBoss related dependencies.  I noticed a strange discrepancy between the POM files of the Scheduler project and a different Spring Boot project.  I might have to add in some JAR files.

Comment: So EJB 1 on JBoss 5?  It has been a while.  Your properties look correct.  If you look at the JNDI view on the web UI, what do you have registered at gibson/SpringSchedulerService?

Comment: Jboss 5.1.0 yes.

I'm not sure what you mean by "If you look at the JNDI view on the web UI, what do you have registered at gibson/SpringSchedulerService?"  You referring to the Scheduler project in applicationContext?

    <bean id="springSchedulerService" class="com.ourcompany.gibson.client.remote.EJBServiceFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="com.ourcompany.gibson.services.scheduler.SpringSchedulerService"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="com.ourcompany.gibson.services.scheduler.ejb.SpringSchedulerServiceHome"/>
    </bean>

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  It's hard for me to give an answer that will necessarily be useful to the next person who runs into this.  It was a problem with dependencies.  I grabbed some JBoss related JAR files from the Do Stuff project and imported to the Scheduler.